# Formatting Source Code programmatically with JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am generating some classes with JDT. Afterwards I would like to format the whole ICompilationUnit, just as if I pressed Ctrl+Shift+F (Source > Format) in an open Editor without a selection.

Any pointers for the API in JDT to format the source code programmatically is highly appreciated.

Addition: I tried it like this, but the code isn't changed. What am I mssing?

```
private void formatUnitSourceCode(ICompilationUnit targetUnit, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws JavaModelException {
    CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
    TextEdit formatEdit = formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, targetUnit.getSource(), 0, targetUnit.getSource().length(), 0, null);
    targetUnit.applyTextEdit(formatEdit, monitor);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be a bug, but using the JDK in Elcipse 4.2.2, it is necessary to create a working copy of the ICompilationUnit in order to apply a TextEdit to the file.

```
    targetUnit.becomeWorkingCopy(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
    ... do work on the source file ...
    formatUnitSourceCode(targetUnit, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
    targetUnit.commitWorkingCopy(true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
```

The formatting itself is done like this:

```
public static void formatUnitSourceCode(ICompilationUnit unit, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws JavaModelException {
    CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
    ISourceRange range = unit.getSourceRange();
    TextEdit formatEdit = formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, unit.getSource(), range.getOffset(), range.getLength(), 0, null);
    if (formatEdit != null && formatEdit.hasChildren()) {
        unit.applyTextEdit(formatEdit, monitor);
    } else {
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 One minor point: `SubProgressMonitor` is now deprecated. Something like `SubMonitor.convert(monitor)` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

When [generating some classes by using JDT](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/05/eclipse-jdt-tutorial-java-model/), you can put "\t"s in your source code. Or like what you did, using code formatter. I have tested the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String code = "public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\"Hello World\");}}";
    CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);

    TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN, code, 0,code.length(),0,null);
    IDocument doc = new Document(code);
    try {
        textEdit.apply(doc);
        System.out.println(doc.get());
    } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

The `apply()` method does the trick here.

Comment: This helps, but it doens't elegantly solve all of the wanted formatting. I. e. you would need to manualy break long method declarations with lots of parameters.

Comment: Very interesting problem. I see what you are doing, and I just edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I changed my code above to use `CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN`, but that didn't work either. Afterwards I checked `targetUnit.getSource()` after the call to `targetUnit.applyTextEdit` (which does the `apply()` on the internal `IDocument` of the `ICompilationUnit`), and strangely the changes seem to be applied. But they are not applied to the file. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I found the solution: I seems to be necessary to create a `workingCopy` of the `ICompilationUnit` to be able to apply the edits to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to format a Java Source file

```
    public static void formatSource(ICompilationUnit cu, IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws JavaModelException{
    String source = cu.getSource();
    IJavaProject javaProject = cu.getJavaProject();

    Map options = javaProject.getOptions(true);


            // Instantiate the default code formatter with the given options
            final CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);


            final TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(
                CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, // format a compilation unit
                source, // source to format
                0, // starting position
                source.length(), // length
                0, // initial indentation
                System.getProperty("line.separator") // line separator
            );          

            cu.becomeWorkingCopy(progressMonitor);
            try {
                cu.applyTextEdit(edit, progressMonitor);
                //cu.reconcile();
                cu.commitWorkingCopy(true, progressMonitor);
                //cu.save(progressMonitor, false);

                JavaUI.openInEditor(cu);


            } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

}
```