# Formatting Source Code Eclipse JDT CTRL+SHIFT+F

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm generating a plugin in Eclipse. My plugin generates source code in an open Editor so I would like to format the whole code (with JDT), just as if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

I have found some information about different class such `ICompilationUnit`, `CodeFormatter`... but I don't have it clear because I have to take the code of the editor formatter and then I have to write in over the editor again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Source Code programmatically with JDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015240/formatting-source-code-programmatically-with-jdt)

Comment: I know that my question is very similar to this. But I don't undestand how can I get ICompilationUnit unit and IProgressMonitor monitor in my editor.

Comment: You will need to understand about the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)